# ftp user created by me from cpanel is unable to access via filezilla while the admin user can access

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I cannot access files via ftp from a user created by me in cpanel but I can access the account created by hosting account.I am using ftpes:// followed by domain name. I get the following error:

```
530 Login authentication failed
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I would like to create a user so that he can make changes in sub-folder(folder named website) this is the path configured to the user and not public-html.
I am a noob in ftp and would appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it : If you have created your own username then you need to type entire username ie:example@example.com with the password provided at the time of creating the ftp account. host name will be ftpes://example.com .Thats it.